# accessing and updating mongo object with keys

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, object, mongoose

I have a mongo schema as below

```
var schema = mongoose.Schema({
user: {type:ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
preferences: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('UserPreference', schema);
```

I'm making a post call with data

```
{
"newQuestionPrompt": false,
"oldQuestion": false
}
```

Each of these properties need to get set into the preferences field, for example

```
"_id" : ObjectId("58f9d06cf998d9baccf8024f"),
"user" : ObjectId("58eda68601dc391e27f3e2c4"),
"preferences":{
 "newQuestionPrompt": false,
 "oldQuestion": false
 }
```

However, when the same post call is made for the same user again, there might be entirely different properties in the call, or the same properties with different values, like

```
{
  "newQuestionPrompt": true,
  "randomQuestion": false
}
```

In this case, I need to update the values of properties which already exist and add the ones which aren't, so the earlier object should become

```
"_id" : ObjectId("58f9d06cf998d9baccf8024f"),
"user" : ObjectId("58eda68601dc391e27f3e2c4"),
"preferences":{
"newQuestionPrompt": true,
"oldQuestion": false,
"randomQuestion": false
}
```

I can't use $set preferences:req.body as it would overwrite the whole thing. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: set Object.assign(oldobjfromdatabase,newobjfromuser)

Comment: Try: `"_id" : ObjectId("58f9d06cf998d9baccf8024f"),
"user" : ObjectId("58eda68601dc391e27f3e2c4"),
"$set":{
"preferences.newQuestionPrompt": false
 }`

Comment: If you use `preferences.newQuestionPrompt` only the `newQuestionPrompt` property will be set without removing the other properties. In other words `preferences.newQuestionPrompt` will only update `newQuestionPrompt` not the entire `preferences` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the incoming call object to an object that has keys with the [dot notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) so that you can use with your **[`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/)** update i.e. converting

```
{
    'newQuestionPrompt': true,
    'randomQuestion': false
}
```

to

```
{
    'preference.newQuestionPrompt': true,
    'preference.randomQuestion': false
}
```

After conversion, you can use it in your update as:

```
UserPreference.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, 
    {
        '$set': {
            'preference.newQuestionPrompt': true,
            'preference.randomQuestion': false
        }
    }, 
    { 'new': true },
    (err, pref) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(pref);
    }
)
```

---

For converting the object, you can try the following approach:

```
let update = { '$set': {} };
let options = { 'new': true };
let cb = (err, pref) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(pref);
};

Object.keys(req.body).forEach((key) => {
    update['$set'][`preference.${key}`] = req.body[key];  
});

UserPreference.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, update, options, cb);
```